# How can we add swap two textbox value button and it's backend code for asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I want to swap values between two textboxes and need to add ui button that will swap values.

It should be like this -

[swap toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPcM2.png)

I tried many expects but didn't find anything yet.
I need it specifically in asp.net and html, css format.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you are looking for and what you have already tried.

Comment: Actually i found my solution. I used a trick and just used the image and set up the function to swap the values and it worked for me. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so say this markup:

```
        <div style="border:solid 1px black;width:220px;padding:5px;float:left" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""
            ></asp:Label>            
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-top:-8px">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="Content/swap2.png"
            OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"
            />

        </div>

        <div style="border:solid 1px black;width:220px;padding:5px;float:left" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="xx"
            ></asp:Label>            
        </div>
```

So, the swap image is a standard button, and the code behind for that button to swap the values looks like this:

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim strTemp As String = Label1.Text
    Label1.Text = Label2.Text
    Label2.Text = strTemp

End Sub
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

The above example used 2 labels, but 2 text boxes would also work.